# Most efficient way of calling children component from Parent in react.js

Tags: reactjs

So this is what i have up to now, but is it the best structure to call a child from the parent?

Or will this simply cause issues further on during application use?

I did previously call the  class from the parent's render method but which is better?

```
var ApiResponseParent = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        fbResponsesState: []
    }

  },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        console.log("parentMounted");
        this.serverRequest = axios.get(`url`)
          .then(res => {
            const fbResponsesState = res.data.fb_responses;
            this.setState({ fbResponsesState });
            console.log(this.state.fbResponsesState);
          });
  },

    componentDidUpdate: function () {
    console.debug('componentDidUpdate');
    return ReactDOM.render(<App fbResponses={this.state.fbResponsesState}/>, document.getElementById("example"));
  },

    render: function () {
        return null;
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({

  render: function () {

      var htmlTables;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.props.fbResponses.length; i++) 
      {
          var fbResponse = this.props.fbResponses[i].data;
          if (fbResponse.length > 0) 
          {

              htmlTables = (<div>
                  <table>
                     ....
                  </table>
              </div>);
          }
          else
          {
              htmlTables = "";
          }

      }
      return (htmlTables ? htmlTables : null);
  }

});

ReactDOM.render(<ApiResponseParent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you reset the state React knows how to re-render appropriately. What you have in componentDidUpdate should be inside the render method of ApiResponseParent. And, when XHR request is complete and you set the fbResponsesState, React will rerender the component with App component getting fresh fbResponses. Remember, React only does minimum required update behind the scene, although we call it 're-rendering'.

```
render: function () {
    return (<App fbResponses={this.state.fbResponsesState}/>);
}
```